# Filtering and Piping

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I am new to R.

I am trying to filter from a column called "Condition" in a dataframe named "completedResponses". I want all of the results to reside in a new dataframe called "lowPol".

```
> library(dplyr)
> low <- c("LowPolPenalty", "LowPolBonus", "LowPolSalary")
> lowPol <- filter(completedResponses,Condition %>% low)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can post your example as code so it is easier to read. Anyways, try: lowPol <- completedResponses %>% filter(Condition %in% low)

Comment: Alfredo, Thanks!  It worked.